# Is hibernate search remote indexing possible?

Tags: java, oracle, indexing, hibernate-search

We are migrating a whole application originally developed in Oracle Forms a few years back, to a Java (7) web based application with Hibernate (4.2.7.Final) and Hibernate Search (4.1.1.Final).

One of the requirements is: as users are using the new migrated version, they able to use the Oracle Forms version - so Hibernate Search indexes will be out of sync. Is it feasable to implement a servlet so that some PL-SQL accesses some link that updates the local indexes in the application server (AS)?

I thought of implementing a some sort clustering mechanism for hibernate, but as I read through the documentation I realised that as clustering may be a good option for scalabillity and performance, for maintaining legacy data in sync may be a bit overkill.

Does anyone have any idea of how to implement a service, accessible via servlet, to update local AS indexes in a given model entity with a given ID?

Comment: Unrelated question: why migrating to old versions of the Hibernate libraries? There are many good reasons to use either the latest community versions, or the latest supported builds by JBoss EAP (neither match the versions you listed)

Comment: The project has been under development for around 2 years now, I believe at the time Hibernate 4 was the latest build - anyway that is completely irrelevant to my case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly you mean by the clustering part, but anyways:

It seems like you are facing a similar problem like me. I am currently in the works of creating a Hibernate-Search adaption for JPA providers (that are not Hibernate-ORM, meaning EclipseLink, TopLink, etc.) and I am working on an automatic reindexing feature at the moment. Since JPA doesn't have a event system suitable for reindexation with Hibernate-Search I came up with the idea to use triggers on a database level to keep track of everything.

For a basic OneToOne relationship it's pretty straight forward and for other things like relation-tables or anything that is not stored in the main table of an entity it gets a bit trickier, but once you got a system for OneToOne relationships it's not that hard to get to that next step. Okay, Let's start:

Imagine two Entities: **Place** and **Sorcerer** in the Lord of the rings universe. In order to keep things simple let's just say they are in a (quite restrictive :D) 1:1 relationship with each other. Normally you end up with 2 tables named SORCERER and PLACE.

Now you have to create 3 triggers (one for CREATE, one for DELETE and one for UPDATE) on each Table (SORCERER and PLACE) that store information about what entity (only the id, for mapping tables there are always multiple ids) has changed and how (CREATE, UPDATE, DELETE) into special UPDATE tables. Let's call these PLACE_UPDATES and SORCERER_UPDATES.

In addition to the ID of the original Object that has changed and the event-type these will need an ID field that is needed to be UNIQUE among all UPDATE tables. This is needed because if you want to feed information from the Update tables to the Hibernate-Search index you have to make sure the events are in the right order or you will break your index. How such an UNIQUE ID can be created on your database should be easy to find on the internet/stackoverflow.

Okay. Now that you have set up the triggers correctly you will just have to find a way to access all the UPDATES tables in a feasible fashion (I do this via querying from multiple tables at once and sorting each query by our UNIQUE id field and then just comparing the first result of each query with the others) and then update my index.

This can be a bit tricky and you have to find the correct ways of dealing with the specific update event but it can be done (that's what I am currently working on).

If you're interested in that part, you can find it here:

https://github.com/Hotware/Hibernate-Search-JPA/blob/master/hibernate-search-db/src/main/java/com/github/hotware/hsearch/db/events/IndexUpdater.java

The link to the whole project is:

https://github.com/Hotware/Hibernate-Search-JPA/

This uses Hibernate-Search 5.0.0.

I hope this was of help (at least a little bit).

And about your remote indexing problem:

The update tables can easily be used as some kind of dump for events until you send them to the remote machine that is to be updated.

Comment: Thank you for your extensive answer - creating an update table for every legacy table in my case is overkill - however I could optimize it using only one UPDATE table that references every other legacy table via a TABLE_DISCRIMINATOR column. One thing is for sure: **I will most def need triggers to call indexing mechanism. My questions is: what is the best way to call an indexing mechanism via DB triggers**. The clustering part: hibernate search offers mechanisms for master and slave workers so that all indexing work is queued in the master, and asked by the slaves (concurrent and lock-safe).

Comment: I don't know whether Oracle DB has ways to send events from the DB to the application, but if it has, you could send an event to an Updater class, that then reads data from your update table. If not you will have to create an Updater class that checks for entries in the update table every x seconds. I know about the clustering system in Hibernate-Search, but how is that related to your legacy update system?

Comment: I see hibernate-search clustering mechanism as an opportunity to avoid indexing directly on a webapp servlet (the servlet would analyse request params, like table and ID, and call an entity manager to update the index according to those params). However, concurrency would be hard to manage since a servlet-indexing service would be single threaded. Hibernate-search natively provides concurrency control with Worker queues. Clustering wouldn't have anything to do direclty with legacy data - it would protect the app on high throughput indexing requests (like legacy triggers requests for indexing)

Comment: I don't think Clustering will save you there. The indexing workload will always be the same, since HSearch doesn't split the workload but instead copies that to other cluster nodes. The clustering aspect of HSearch is focused on searching! Also if you are using legacy triggers you will have to make sure that the index is updated in the right order. What if the DELETE event comes before an INDEX event, but you do it in the opposite order?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7692464/hibernate-search-in-a-clustered-configuration

Comment: Also note that HibernateSearch does provide a **WorkQueue** not a **WorkerQueue**